# Which folder to put email templates in, when sending from admin?

Tags: templates, admin, silverstripe

I've inherited some code that doesn't work, where a button (with a custom function) exists in the admin page for particular dataobject, and triggers an email to be sent. The code is currently trying to populate the body of the email by using a template file, which is currently in the theme folder for the site.

However, the email body is blank, as the template is not being found. My understanding is that the admin section of the site doesn't look in the theme folder for templates. Where can I put the template (and the other templates it includes) where they can be found from code in the admin part of the site?

```
$email = new Email($sender_email, $recipient_email, "Your order has been shipped!");
$email->setTemplate("OrderShipped");
$email->populateTemplate(array("Order" => $order));
$email->send();
```

The error being output to the error log is this:

```
[17-Nov-2014 14:34:01] Warning at framework/view/SSViewer.php line 780: None
of these templates can be found in theme 'mytheme': OrderShipped.ss 
(http://mytestsite.co.nz/admin/orders/MyOrder/EditForm/field/MyOrder)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the theme is not set when in the backend of the CMS, templates should not be in the themes folder. You can try to move the file into mysite/templates/Email for the main email template. Any includes can be stored in mysite/templates/Includes.

Comment: Thanks; I've tried that and it still doesn't seem to find it. The error log is still showing an error (I've appended it to the question). And yes I did remember to do a flush, and the file permissions look fine! I don't suppose you can tell me where to add some debugging to determine which directories are being looked in for templates?

Comment: Ensure you use flush=all, and not flush=1. It looks like you have theme set though, 'mytheme'. Did you try to place the template file under /themes/mytheme/templates (and not a subfolder of it). If that still doesn't work, you can look a what is happening inside SS_TemplateLoader#findTemplates() and debug from there

Comment: Yes, I used flush=all. No luck with themes/mytheme/templates. I think I'll have to start tracing through the framework code...

Comment: When adding or changing template files you also should (on my servers it is always necessary) remove the cached files in the /tmp folder. Every silverstripe site has a special folder in the /tmp, it starts with /tmp/silverstripe-...

Answer (score 1):

as jfbarrois wrote, the theme is not set in CMS. So I used this small hack and it started to work:

```
Config::inst()->update('SSViewer', 'theme_enabled', true);
Config::inst()->update('SSViewer', 'theme', 'mysite');

 // change 'mysite' with the name of your theme
```

and you can keep the template in "*mysite/templates/Email*". 
Maybe there's also some other option how to do that, but I haven't found it yet.